# Targeted firebase push notification for custom claim roles with firebase auth in flutter app #AskFirebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement firebase messaging in flutter app.... I had a problem in midway,,,, that if i have 2 types of users say teacher and student using the same app with different role... i need to send notification to students when teacher publishes a test result..... but other teachers doesn't need to....

Now users collection has device list ( device token ids ) for that particular user in what ever device he's logged in, the roles are defined in custom claims not in db

is it possible to send push notification with type of users...[ role based ].... when the roles are defined in custom claims not in db

Comment: It sounds possible. Do you have code that isn't working the way you expect? Are you stuck on some specific problem with your implementation?

Comment: the user roles are associated in custom claims, but i need to send push nofication to all users of certain role groups through cloud function... how do i create query to this criteria.... 

if the role is in db, i can do a filter....   its doesn't seems correct but alternate i have is.... to fetch all user id from db, run another query to get all their claims and separate those with required role, and again fire a query to get their device tokens......

here i have to fire multiple query .... this looks like workaround.. there should be correct way right?

Comment: You can certainly use a database to store and query for users whose criteria match what you want.

Comment: Yeah Exactly.... i was in right track.. unless....  but my condition of role lies in custom claims of identity management service [ firebaseAuth ] not in DB.. so how to role roles from DB when its not there !!!